# How to set file permissions (user/group) and access mode in Boost.log in UNIX

Tags: c++, unix, logging, boost, file-permissions

I would like to create logfiles always with the same user/group permission (UNIX) instead of the current executing user permissions. Also I want to set the access mode of the files. How can I do that when I create the logfile.

I am using boost library: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/log/doc/html/index.html

Using system() commands to execute chown(),chgrp() and chmod() is possible, but only after closing the file. This isn't good, because the programm can run for a long long time.

```
#include "Logger.h"

using namespace logging::trivial;


Logger::Logger(string path, string fileName) {

    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this->path = path;
    this->fileName = fileName;
    logging::add_file_log
    (
        keywords::file_name = path + "/" + fileName + "_%d.%m.%Y.log", // Name of the Logfile
        keywords::open_mode = std::ios_base::app, // is used to attach Events to an existing Logfile
        keywords::time_based_rotation = sinks::file::rotation_at_time_point(0, 0, 0), //is used to create a new Logfile at 12:00pm
        keywords::auto_flush = true,
        keywords::format =
                (
                    expr::stream
                        <<expr::format_date_time< boost::posix_time::ptime >("TimeStamp", "[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S]")
                        << ": " << expr::smessage)
    );// specified the Format  "[%TimeStamp%]: %Message%"


}
```